# How could I improve this Python script to replace records in dbf file?

Tags: python, dbf

I have a dbf file with about 9 million records and 2.5 GB size.
A lot of space is taken up by a 80 size character field used to store 1 of about 10 different character strings. 
To save on file size, I want to replace the character field by an integer field and use a relational database at a later stage to get the full character field if needed.

Currently I have the following Python script which uses the dbf library (http://pythonhosted.org/dbf/). The script seems to be working (tested on a smaller dbf file), but it runs for several hours when I try to run it with the full dbf file.

```
import dbf

tabel = dbf.Db3Table('dataset.dbf')
tabel.open()

with tabel:
 tabel.add_fields('newfield N(2, 0)')
 for record in tabel:
     if record.oldfield == 'string_a                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=1)
     elif record.oldfield == 'string_b                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=2)
     elif record.oldfield == 'string_c                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=3)
     elif record.oldfield == 'string_d                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=4)
     elif record.oldfield == 'string_e                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=5)
     elif record.oldfield == 'string_f                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=6)
     elif record.oldfield == 'string_g                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=7)
     elif record.oldfield == 'string_h                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=8)
     elif record.oldfield == 'string_i                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=9)
     elif record.oldfield == 'string_j                                                                        ':
         dbf.write(record, newfield=10)
     else:
         dbf.write(record, newfield=0)

dbf.delete_fields('dataset.dbf', 'oldfield')
```

As you may be able to see from the code, I am new to both Python and the dbf library. Can this script be made to run more efficiently?

Comment: Why not try to use sql_update to this: https://pythonhosted.org/dbf/dbf-pysrc.html#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding and deleting fields will both first make a backup copy of your 2.5GB file.

Your best bet is to make a new dbf with the same structure as the original, with the exception of those two fields; then as you copy each record make the changes.  Something like:

```
# lightly untested

old_table = dbf.Table('old_table.dbf')
structure = old_table.structure()
old_field_index = structure.index('oldfield')
structure = structure[:old_field_index] + structure[old_field_index+1:]
structure.append('newfield N(2,0)')
new_table = dbf.Table('new_name_here.dbf', structure)

with dbf.Tables(old_table, new_table):
    for rec in old_table:
        rec = list(rec)
        old_value = rec.pop(old_field_index)
        rec.append(<transform old_value into new_value>)
        new_table.append(tuple(rec))
```

Comment: Great. It did the trick in under 40 minutes. Only had to make one minor modification since it could not append rec as a list, only as a tuple. Thanks.

Comment: @St_Del:  Thanks for that!  Fixed.

Comment: @EthanFurman not only wrote the dbf module but he also gives amazing support here at stackoverflow. Awesome guy.